# jQuery.children selects parent too

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML;

```
<div id="pic_options_container">
  <div id="pic_options_header">header text</div>
  <div id="pic_options_org"></div>
  <div id="pic_options_preview"><img id="imgPreview" src="" /></div></div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to achieve is; When clicked on pic_options_container the children of that div should hide. However, pic_options_container itself also gets hidden.

```
$('#pic_options_container').click(function () {
    $(this).children().hide();
});
```

Anyone know of a solution or tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Assign a `min-height` and I'd imagine you'll see that the parent is *not* being hidden. But without contents it won't have a height, without which you can't see it.

Comment: It works fine look.. The pic_options_container does not hide.  Only the children http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/BzPym/

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it gets hidden? I bet you it just gets "emptied" and it collapses to 0 width and height.

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/SmSGS/

Comment: you get the idea... I am wandering even though I use children(), why the parent also disappears..

Comment: it doesn't disappear, it just doesn't have width and heigh so you can't see it. It basically acts like: <div id="pic_options_container "></div>

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$('#pic_options_container').click(function () {
    $(this).hide(); // to hide container it self, not chldren
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/57Dd9/2/)**

But to hide children and both container:

```
$('#pic_options_container').click(function () {
    $(this).children().hide().end().hide(); // to hide container it self
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/57Dd9/1/)**

#### About invalid markup

```
<div id="pic_options_preview"><img id="imgPreview" src="" /></div></div>
```

an extra closing `</div>` in the end, correct that.

Comment: I only want to hide the children. not the container itself

Comment: @Emin then first one is suit for you

Answer (score 0):

You have to give an **height** and **width** to see your 'pic_options_container' container if it doesnt has childrens or are hidded.